# How To Disable Action Animations When Firing?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

It feels like the firing animations take a ridiculously long time, and although I don't have hard data, I think they take the majority of my missions. The sniper animation is especially egregious, I don't want to watch a guy take 5+ seconds to line up a shot and then miss it.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to disable the animations but with the [XCOM ToolBoks](http://www.nexusmods.com/xcom/mods/79/?) you can speed up other aspects of combat.